# Remove mod pings from TL

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

The current mod ping only has one purpose

For example a site X

> ModfromsiteXalreadyinroom: yeah so as I was saying
> Derp: xi mods: Do you want this?
> Feeds: Unknown site "xi.stackexchange.com", don't know who to ping. Don't blame me, I'm just a bot
> Derp: x mods:
> Feeds: 3 moderators summoned: ModfromsiteXalreadyinroom, ModYwhonevercomesintoom, ModZ
> Derp: ^^^^
> Derp: You want this question? stackquestion.com/2

In the original feature request [We need a way for moderators to ping a group of people in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101765/we-need-a-way-to-ping-a-group-of-people-in-chat) there was a need for decay or removal of ping when one mod addresses it, but this doesn't happen, so in the end 2 out of 3 mods waste their time. 2 years ago it sounded like a great idea, now it's just annoying and abused.

*Example what's the sense of pinging all these guys*

> Bill the Lizard, Michael Myers, Will, Robert Harvey, Kev, BoltClock, NullUserException, casperOne, jjnguy, George Stocker, Brad Larson, ThiefMaster, Andrew Barber, ChrisF, Gordon, Flexo

In addition https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/, states

> The migration tool was created to help those unfortunate users who asked good questions on the wrong site.
>
> Don’t migrate poorly-asked or non-constructive questions. Just close them. If you want to help the asker out by recommending a site where their question would be on-topic, go ahead – but also recommend they read that site’s FAQ first!

In summary, I am saying if the mod ping tool was used properly it would be to say

> Derp: x mods: I read your FAQ and think this is a really good question for your site. What do you think

Even then, if you know it's a good question, might as well just migrate it.

Comment: While I do find this useful on occasion, I cringe everytime I see someone use it for SO mods... Long-term, I don't think it's going to scale well.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't disagree, but SO mods use it to tell other SO mods when they'll not be handling flags, away for extended periods of time, etc.  I don't think this should go away, but I think we should find a way to make people not use it for things like migration of questions, etc.

Comment: @Shog9 For what it's worth though, the number of SO mods that actually see the ping vs the number of mods that are pinged is low, so I agree with the statement that the tool is pretty high-noise now when used improperly.

Comment: It sounds like what we really need is for one responding mod to be able to dismiss the ping for his peers.  As a non-SO mod I find being pinged this way useful, but for SO it's just crazy.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that the mod ping is overused, but there are still valid uses for it outside of migration. And using it for SO is IMO only justified if you have something important that *all* SO mods should know.

It's an easy shortcut for notifying all your fellow mods about something, of course we could look up the individual mods but that gets annoying, especially when you have to use the superping. There are also valid reasons to talk to the mods of another site, especially for closely related sites.

At minimum, I would keep the `whois` feature which is rather handy and can't be easily abused. But I'm not yet convinced that the current problem can't be solved by better user education.

I'll add that the mod ping was implemented the less useful way anyway. What I would have wanted was a ping *any* mod instead of the ping *all* mods we got, which is a lot noisier and notifies too many users in most cases.

Comment: `there are still valid uses for it outside of migration` like?

Comment: if you cannot be bothered to see someone from Y site already in the TL then I don't see it as annoying.

Comment: @phwd They're pretty rare, I'll give you that. But I remember seeing them used for stuff like asking the mods of a similar site for advice about certain topics, or for coordinating on a cross-site user problem.

Comment: @phwd - I know that I've used it for site-wide announcements, like "I'm going to be offline for the next week" or "watch out for a cluster of spammers from this IP who are targeting the site right now." I've found notifications like that to be very helpful, so that I don't wonder why someone isn't responding or so that I'm made aware of something going down while I was away.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a feature to `whois` that indicates which of those mods are currently in TL, if any.

Comment: Worst case, an erroneous ping costs me a few seconds to click through it. If someone is misusing these, they're quickly educated and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the mod ping is overused, but that doesn't make it *bad*.

Here are some legit uses:

- "Hey, `<site> mods`! A spammer on our site has decided to scooch over to yours! Keep a watch!" (also works for trolls)
- Leaving notes to mods on your own sites. Many sites have mod rooms, many don't.

I've also seen it used for summoning site mods for miscellaneous private discussions/announcements/pokes.

I do agree that it shouldn't be used that often. The protocol *should* be:

- Determine if you really need to ping all mods
- Run a `whois`
- If any mod is around, ping them instead
- If not, pick the most recently active ones and ping
- If there aren't any recently active ones, *then* use the ping.

---

I actually have a plan for a userscript (or bot, if it's allowed), to replace the TL bot. The script will basically show you a list of mods, sorted by "most likely to hear your message first" (a mixture of their last activity and their general activity trends). You can pick as many as you want and it will craft a superping for that.

Unfortunately, I can't get this done until there's a way to reliably get chat IDs from network profile/site profile IDs. (Or I would have to manually curate this dataset.)